# Dynamically allocated object property isn't rendering on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a booking application and have a bunch of events that I'm rendering. In each event, I've added a dynamic boolean value which is going to depend on whether the user has already booked the event. If the value is true I want to disable the button, if it's not, show it. The problem I'm facing is that although I'm able to set the property for each object, when I pass it down as a prop, it doesn't render properly. Instead, If I go to the second page and then come back it'll be properly displayed.

```
const getEvents = async(user_id) =>{
    try{
        const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/locations");
         var events = data.data.data;
         const isWish = 'isWish'
         events.map(el => {
               //check if it's booked
             let isSelected = checkWish(user_id, el.Id);
             (isSelected.then(function(data){
                  if(data === true){
                      el[isWish]=true;
                  } else if(data === false){
                      el[isWish]=false;
                  }
             }));
         })
         //dispatch the new objects to the reducer
        dispatch({type:GET_EVENTS, payload:events});

    } catch{

    }

}
```

Then in the Events component, I'm calling the `useEffect()` hook and getting the objects out of the state, looping through them with the `map()` and passing it as a prop the `EventsItem` component which is going to render each object.

`{currentPost.map((event) =><EventItem excursion={event} user={user}></EventItem>)}`

Finally I perform the necessary check

```
    const EventItem = ({excursion, user}) => {

   const {Company, City, Picture, ShortDescription, Id, isWish} = excursion;
  return (
     <div>
 {isWish ? <button>I'm disabled</button> : <button>I'm disabled</button>}
    </div>
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

So given the fact that I'm doing two database calls inside on function, I decided to wrap the `dispatch` inside a `setTimeOut()` because the only logical thing that I came up with is that the value doesn't load fast enough when I'm rendering the page and it worked!